# how to pass a gensym to a function name in common lisp

Tags: function, macros, common-lisp

I'm using Lucerne to build an api, and experimenting with generating those apis based off of a list (they're very simple endpoints).  The problem is that the views lucerne uses are just functions, so if I pass `(gensym)` to the macro at runtime the name of that view function is just set to `(gensym)` (or it fails, can't remember which).

I'd like to dynamically name a set of those view functions in a macro that will be in a loop of some kind, each time the code that macro has expanded too is run the functions have a new name (so if I just use a standard `gensym` each time the macro was run each of the functions would always have the same name, and overwrite each other).  Is there some way to do this?

Comment: When you say "the macro is run", can you be a bit more precise? Do you mean "when the macro-expansion is executed" or "when the macro is expanded"?

Comment: I think you need to be more precise about what you want.  The macro is 'run' (expanded), typically, once, when the code is compiled (although expansion may happen any number of times).  At runtime the code that the macro expanded *into* is evaluated, possibly many times.  If you want lots of gensyms a runtime, then *that* code needs to call `gensym`.  But if you are using these to name functions this is very likely an XY problem.

Answer (score 1):

You probably want to use [`intern`](http://clhs.lisp.se/Body/f_intern.htm) to create "public" symbols (that the users will be calling by name) and [`make-symbol`](http://clhs.lisp.se/Body/f_mk_sym.htm) for "private" symbols (that are stored somewhere).